# Can not inject Spring's Service with ManagedProperty

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2.2, web.xml

I have a web app with JSF 2.2, Spring 4, ang Hibernate Integration. When I try to inject a Spring Service with ManagedProperty in a ManagedBean I have a Nullpointer Exception:

```
 @ManagedBean
 @ViewScoped
 public class SuperAdminNuevasAppBean {
 @ManagedProperty(value = "#{appService}")
    private AppService appService;
 //Code
}
```

AppService is an interface:

```
public interface AppService {

public abstract void persist(App transientInstance);

public abstract void remove(App persistentInstance);

public abstract App merge(App detachedInstance);
//
}
```

This is the implementation:

```
@Service
public class AppServiceImpl implements AppService {

@Autowired
private AppDAO appDAO;

@Autowired
private EdificioDAO edificioDAO;

@Override
@Transactional
public void persist(App transientInstance) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    appDAO.persist(transientInstance);
}
 //More code...
```

If I put

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{appServiceImpl}")
private AppService appService;
```

everything works ok.
I have the getters and setters, the org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver in faces-config, the org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener and  org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener in web.xml. Is this the right behavior?

Comment: Yes it is. As the name of the bean is generated based on the name of the class unless you specify it. And as `@ManagedProperty` does injection based on names yes it is the expected and correct behavior.

Comment: Have you find the answer? If yes, please share with me. thanks